# set Notification forspreadsheet trigger in google apps script onEdit()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a trigger for spreadsheet onEdit(). This works fine.

What I want to achieve: When I set the trigger programmatically, by default the notification is set to "Daily" and "around 3 am". How do I set this to "immediately" using script?

Here's my code for setting up the trigger.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("notify").forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no support for configuring trigger failure notifications in Google Apps Script. Visit [Issue 1287](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1287) and star it to "vote", and receive updates.

Comment: oh ok. can we write our own custom trigger in GAS? Like, the above trigger will notify the user by mail when a spreadsheet gets updated. but the problem is, it sends continuously 'n' number of mails when to the user for each and every edit. how do i over come that? i want the script to act like, the user should receive only one mail even though he made many changes at once. is it possible to write custom trigger like that?

Comment: You should ask that as a different question.